# Laptop with arch: On Battery slow and low battery life

Tags: arch-linux, laptop

My laptop with arch (new laptop) with an i7, 32gb ram and 1tb ssd nvme is so slow on battery. Also the battery life only lasts 1h????

What I tried:

- Configure performance mode in BIOS
- TLP (With this disabled laptop works fine, so this is the cause of the laptop being slow on battery)

What can I do to improve the situation?

Comment: Maybe start with comparing the battery capacity (`tlp-stat -s`) with the output of `powertop`. My guess is that the CPU needs so much power that the battery drains very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue with my i5, it heats up and use too much battery power while being throttled.

You can try [Laptop Mode tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop_Mode_Tools) and see if your situation gets better.

If you want to stay with TLP, you can give a try to [TLPUI](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tlpui) and personalize your configuration. I lowered my max frequency from 3.5 GHz to 2.5 (which is throttling). This way I gained ~1 hour of autonomy.

Pay attention to hardware acceleration which is [disabled by default](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration#Application_support) in Firefox for example. I gained a lot of autonomy activating it (CPU usage while watching a video decreased from 50% to 20%).
You didn't mention any graphics card so I don't know if this will help you.

Lastly, if you use gnome you have a package called [`power-profiles-daemon`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/power-profiles-daemon/) that conflicts with TLP. It is less customizable. The opinions on it [are mixed](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/qpaa4g/tlp_vs_powerprofilesdaemon/) (on Fedora at least).